# Set variable within callback function with JS module pattern

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, ecmascript-6, module-pattern, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the YouTube iframe api to load a video that i can then perform actions on.

Im using browserify to create modular behaviour and am using the JS module pattern to break part my code.

When I kick off the `createYT` function Im using the `YouTubeIframeLoader` that creates an instance of the `YT.Player` in its callback.

I would like to assign the `YT.Player` to a variable that I can access in other functions of my module. Here is that I have so far

```
const videos = {
   init: function() {
      this.loadYT();
      this.changeVid();
   },
   loadYT: function() {
      YouTubeIframeLoader.load(function(YT) {
        var player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'fObfRDB0JQw'
        });
      });
   },
   changeVid: function() {
       // access player var to perform methods on YT.Player instance
   }
};

export default videos;
```

Comment: In addition to the existing answer, don't forget that `YouTubeIframeLoader.load` is a *callback* so you probably won't be able to call `loadYT` and `changeVid` one after another. Use Promises here

Comment: Ah right that makes alot of sense, what would be the best way of implementing a promise using this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to assign the `YT.Player` to a variable that I can access in other functions of my module.

The solution to this is quite simple: declare a variable in the outer-most scope of your module and assign it a value within `loadYT`. For example:

```
// Declare `player` here instead
let player;

const videos = {
   //...
   loadYT: function() {
      YouTubeIframeLoader.load(function(YT) {
        // Assign value to `player`
        player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'fObfRDB0JQw'
        });
      });
   },
   changeVid: function() {
       if (player) {
           // Use `player` here...
       }
       else {
           // Handle `player` not initialised... or throw an Error
           throw new Error('player not initialised');
       }
   }
};

export default videos;
```

As @RGraham has mentioned in his comment, you may want to change the behaviour of `init` such that it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves when the callback given to `YouTubeIframeLoader.load` is invoked. This way you can be sure that initialisation is complete when consuming the remaining APIs (e.g. `changeVid`) within a `then` callback.

```
let resolve, reject, promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res;
    reject = rej;
});    

let initialised = false;
let player;

const videos = {
   init: function() {
       if (!initialised) this.loadYT();
       return promise;
   },
   loadYT: function() {
      YouTubeIframeLoader.load(function(YT) {
        // Assign value to `player`
        player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'fObfRDB0JQw'
        });
        initialised = true;
        resolve();
      });
      return promise;
   },
   changeVid: function() {
       if (player) {
           // Use `player` here...
       }
       else {
           // Handle `player` not initialised... or throw an Error
           throw new Error('player not initialised');
       }
   }
};

export default videos;
```

Example usage:

```
videos.init().then(() => {
    videos.changeVid();
});
```